# Sum of arrays in a snowflake column

Tags: performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column in a snowflake table, each row in the column has a array of floats of 360 elements. I want to write a snowflake query, so that I get an aggregate of all the elements in the array, such that the out is 360 values. All the element 1 are summed, all the element at index 2 are summed and so on.
The result of the query is a single array of 360 values.

Any idea how I can achieve that in most efficient way, as I need to sum a million records in one query.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a "please make my code for me" site, but "I have this piece of code, that I've tried to make work but cant figure out why it's not working, could you perhaps read this small and nice example that gives the error and help me out?" site. Try to solve your question, and rewrite the issue as a small and reproducible example, illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your table is called ARRAY_DEMO and your arrays are in a column called ARRAY1. The following SQL should do what you want:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(sum_val::integer) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY index ASC)
FROM (
SELECT f.index, sum(f.value) sum_val
  FROM array_demo ad,
  lateral flatten(input => ad.array1) f
GROUP BY f.index
)
;
```

You may need to adjust the "::integer" depending on the type of data you have in your array

Comment: Thank you so much @NickW! The query does exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks!!!